# Pandas split gender column to two columns

Tags: python, pandas, split, pandas-groupby

I have the following table:
https://ibb.co/DMGCgD2

I want to split (Property Type) to two column count_Single_Family and count_Multi_Family in each zip code:

I used this code but I don't know what to do next:

`b=Combineddf[Combineddf['Property Type']=='Multi-Family'].count()
a=Combineddf[Combineddf['Property Type']=='Single Family'].count()`

I can do this with sql but I keep trying to get it to work with pandas but no luck. Thank you for the help.
Edit* 
Input:

```
    import pandas as pd
input= pd.DataFrame({'Zip Code': [90001, 90001, 90001,90002,90002,90002], 
                   'Total Males': [28468, 28468, 28468,43533,43533,43533],
                  'Total Female': [32135, 32135, 32135,54354,54354,54354],
                   'Property Type': ['Multi-Family', 'Multi-Family', 'Single Family','Single Family','Single Family','Multi-Family']
                  })
input
```

Desired output:

```
    out = pd.DataFrame({'Zip Code': [90001, 90001, 90001,90002,90002,90002], 
                       'Total Males': [28468, 28468, 28468,43533,43533,43533],
                      'Total Female': [32135, 32135, 32135,54354,54354,54354],
                       'Multi-Family': [2, 2, 2,1,1,1],
                       'Single Family': [1, 1, 1,2,2,2],

                      })
out
```

Comment: Use [groupby.count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html)

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler this is from csv file i fixed the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) + [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Pandas has a method to cross-tabulate based on an index and values. You then need only merge these results with your original dataframe.

```
df_cross = pd.crosstab(df['Zip Code'], df['Property Type'])

res = df.merge(df_cross, left_on='Zip Code', right_index=True)

print(res)

   Zip Code  Total Males  Total Female  Property Type  Multi-Family  \
0     90001        28468         32135   Multi-Family             2   
1     90001        28468         32135   Multi-Family             2   
2     90001        28468         32135  Single Family             2   
3     90002        43533         54354  Single Family             1   
4     90002        43533         54354  Single Family             1   
5     90002        43533         54354   Multi-Family             1   

   Single Family  
0              1  
1              1  
2              1  
3              2  
4              2  
5              2
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to yield the right solution:

```
v = input.groupby(['Zip Code','Property Type']).count().reset_index().pivot(index='Zip Code',columns = 'Property Type',values = 'Total Males')

pd.merge(input,v, how = 'inner', left_on = 'Zip Code', right_on ='Zip Code').drop('Property Type',axis = 1)
```

Comment: how does v.columns look for you?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
(pd.concat([input.set_index('Zip Code'), 
            input.groupby('Zip Code')['Property Type']
                 .value_counts()
                 .unstack()], axis=1)
).reset_index()

   Zip Code  Total Males  Total Female  Property Type  Multi-Family  Single Family
0     90001        28468         32135   Multi-Family             2              1
1     90001        28468         32135   Multi-Family             2              1
2     90001        28468         32135  Single Family             2              1
3     90002        43533         54354  Single Family             1              2
4     90002        43533         54354  Single Family             1              2
5     90002        43533         54354   Multi-Family             1              2
```